# Processing the Search String with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of making a web page that's meant to display data that's within a database. The database is stored in `MySQL` and I'm making the web page in `PHP`. The `PHP` code that I have is

```
<?php
    $query = "select * from project where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($results);

    echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
    for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Title: ";
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
        echo "</strong><br />Author: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['author']);
        echo "<br />ISBN: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
        echo "<br />Price: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['price']);
        echo "</p>";
    }
    $mysqli_free_result($result);
    $mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

This `PHP` script is meant to load different projects that's within the database and in a `welcome.php` script that calls this script connects to the database and it does connect to it correctly. The problem that I'm having is when I run this script, is that I get the following:

```
Number of projects found:
```

As shown, it doesn't display any data from the database.

**EDIT**

My `welcome.php` script is

```
<?php
    $hostname='mysql.uniwebsite.ac.uk';
    $database='uniusername';
    $username='database';
    $password='password';

    $db= mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{
         echo "Connection to MySQL server " .$hostname . " successful!
    " . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t select database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        echo 'Database ' . $database . ' successfully selected!';
    }


?>
```

**EDIT #2**

My `projects.php` code is

```
<?php
    $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
    $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
    if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
        echo 'No search details. Go back and try again.';
        exit;
    }

    $query = "select * from project where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
    var_dump($query);

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
    for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Project Number: ";
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['projectNo']));
        echo "</strong><br />Project Name: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['pjname']);
        echo "<br />Project City: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['city']);
        echo "</p>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

And when I run it, I get `No search details. Go back and try again.`

**EDIT #3**

In my `projects.php` I have now got

```
        <form action="list_projects.php" method="post">
        <p>Choose Search Type: <br /></p>
        <select name="searchtype">
            <option value="partNo">Part Number</option>
            <option value="pname">Part Name</option>
            <option value="color">Part Colour</option>
            <option value="weight">Part Weight</option>
            <option value="city">City</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <p>Enter Search Term: </p>
        <br />
        <input name="searchterm" type="text" size="20"/>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>

    <?php
        $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
        $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
        if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
            echo 'No search details. Go back and try again.';
            exit;
        }

        $query = "select * from project where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
        var_dump($query);

        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
        for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Part Number: ";
            echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['partNo']));
            echo "</strong><br />Part Name: ";
            echo stripslashes($row['pname']);
            echo "<br />Part Colour: ";
            echo stripslashes($row['color']);
            echo "<br />Part Weight: ";
            echo stripslashes($row['weight']);
            echo "<br />City";
            echo stripcslashes($row['city']);
            echo "</p>";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

but when I run it, I get `string(49) "select * from project where projectNo like '%J1%'"
Number of projects found:`

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @Ian Sorry! I'll add the problem into the question now

Comment: Can you `var_dump($db)`?

Comment: @Marcus I can connect to the database. As I get `Connection to MySQL server mysql.uniwebsite.ac.uk successful! Database database successfully selected!`

Comment: Yup, removed my comment. I totally misread what you said. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Ian where would I put `var_dump($db)`?

Comment: @user3283410 after you have declared it and connected to the database

Comment: And you're sure `$searchtype` and `$searchterm` are set? If you `echo $query;` do you get expected results? In debugging mode, you really need to be checking errors. `$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die( mysqli_error($db) );`

Comment: @Ian so in the `welcome.php` file that connects to the database? So it would look like: 

`else { echo 'Database ' . $database . ' successfully selected!'; } mysql_close($link); var_dump($db);`

Comment: Wait.. can you post your entire `welcome.php` file please? All the code that connects your DB. *You can blur out the password if you like.

Comment: There are two mystery things in your comment: you are using `$link` variable for DB connection but then using `$db` and also closing the DB connection before calling queries on it ... yeah, the full script will help to understand the whole thing ...

Comment: You're closing the connection immediately after you open it.

Comment: @Marcus I've just seen that and taken it out, I'll re-edit it so it's correct

Comment: @Marcus I've just seen your updated question, and I have used `$link` instead of `$db` and I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: I don't even know what's going on anymore. You keep changing the variables in your original post. You had `$link` as your connector, but now it's `$db`. Was that the problem?

Comment: This was originally: `$link= mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);` and now it's: `$db= mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);`. Whatever you use in your connection script is what you need to use throughout your script. Now you have $db holding the connection, so update the rest of your code BACK to `$db` instead of `$link`

Comment: `if (!$link) {` should be `if (!$db) {`

Comment: @Marcus so the `$link` in all the files should be `$db`?

Comment: `$db = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);` `$db` is holding the connection in this case, therefore, it must be used anywhere a connection is needed, eg. `mysqli_close($db);` etc. A while back you were holding the connection in a variable called `$link` which is why I suggested you change everything to `$link`. But now you're using `$db so everything must be `$db`. You can call that variable anything you like, but it must be reflected throughout the script.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Here are the both files corrected. There were few more typos with function names like `$mysqli_free_result($result)` and `$mysqli_close($db)`.

File `welcome.php`:

```js
<?php
    $hostname='mysql.uniwebsite.ac.uk';
    $database='uniusername';
    $username='database';
    $password='password';

    $link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{
         echo "Connection to MySQL server " .$hostname . " successful!
    " . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t select database: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        echo 'Database ' . $database . ' successfully selected!';
    }
?>
```

```js
<?php
    $query = "select * from project where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%'";
    // var_dump($query); -- uncomment to make sure the final query makes sense after filling those variables

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    echo "<p>Number of projects found: ".$num_results."</p>";
    for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Title: ";
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
        echo "</strong><br />Author: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['author']);
        echo "<br />ISBN: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
        echo "<br />Price: ";
        echo stripslashes($row['price']);
        echo "</p>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: I've changed it so it's like that, but I'm still not getting an output

Comment: Well, also try to `var_dump($query)` and make sure the SQL query (after evaluating your variables `$searchtype` and `$searchterm` is syntactically correct. It is possible that there is error in your SQL syntax, the database response with an error and then `mysqli_num_rows` would result with a null.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now the same connection variable is used everywhere, the results->result is corrected and two typos with function names at the bottom. Also make sure the final query makes sense before sending to the database (uncomment the var_dump)

Comment: `$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($results);` still hasn't been corrected.

Comment: OP give the above a try. And *uncomment* the `var_dump($query);` and post the output here, as well, just to be certain you're even passing a valid statement to the query.

Comment: When I run it now, I get `string(38) "select * from project where like '%%'"
Number of projects found:`

Comment: As you can see, there is something wrong. Both variables were empty and were not filled into the query. The query is then incorrect and the MySQL server will not process it correctly and will return error -> then also the function for getting rows fail on it. Check the two variables you are using ...

Comment: Thought so. I made that suggestion quite a while back to echo that out and see if those variables were even set properly. Doesn't look like `$searchtype` and `$searchterm` are being set. You're going to need to figure that out as well.

Comment: @Marcus I've just put `$searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
   $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);
   if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
    echo 'No search details. Go back and try again.';
    exit;
   }`
And I've got `No search details. Go back and try again.` when I run it

Comment: @user3283410 can you update your code and add where you are evaluating this code?

Comment: Well, so as you said you added this check to your code just now. It's obvious that the two POST variables are not set or contain empty value. Make sure you are setting them and sending from your HTML form properly. After they will contain the right data the rest should works ...

Comment: @FilipMatthew How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user3283410 Well, if you are using `$_POST` in your PHP code but don't know where the data inside are get from we stuck in very essentials. Try to study a little first for example here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: @FilipMatthew I've just been working on it and I've managed to get somewhere, so someone can select different things and the `searchtype` and `searchterm` are declared. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Run `mysqli_error($link);` after your `$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);` line and post what you got. Btw. why is your form action leading to **list_supplier.php** when the file with processing the POST is called **projects.php** ?

Comment: @FilipMatthew I have done and it came up with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Remove `mysql_close($link);`

And then, instead of using `$db` in the rest of your code, use `$link`.

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

Comment: I've changed it, but I'm still not getting an output